Can GCP consume from an Aurora Postgres read replica?
I do have an Aurora PostgreSQL 16 global database cluster in AWS with primary and secondary regions. Datalake is set up in Google Cloud Platform (GCP).
In order to consume data from PostgreSQL in AWS, GCP's solution guides to create a publication and a replication slot in order to process CDC. However, these slots can only be created in a primary instance.
SQL Error [25006]: ERROR: cannot execute CREATE PUBLICATION in a read-only transaction
SQL Error [55000]: ERROR: replication slots cannot be used on RO (Read Only) node

Since it's a transactional database, best practice is to avoid attaching datalake consumer on primary cluster but I'm not seeing alternatives here. There are any other ways to replicate CDC data from Postgres in AWS to GCP?

Ain't no such thing as "Postgre".
